# Does SignalR support any form of automatic parameter validation?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm just starting my SignalR journey and don't seem able to find any information on automatic validation of input from clients such as seen in MVC & web api controllers!

Is there anything that I'm missing or is it back to good old manual checking?

Comment: are you pointing something like  user exists checking validation ?

Comment: No - I'm not talking about authentication of the user - just bog standard validation of inputs into hub methods - checking that the user has provided details in their chat message for instance!

Comment: you are talking about checking validation of data in hub , right ?